# Varying definition of Controllability Gramian

Tags: definite-integrals, dynamical-systems

I have always used the following definition of controllability gramian of $(A,B)$ over the time window $[t_0,t_f]$
$$W_c[t_0,t_f] = \int_{t_0}^{t_f}e^{A(t_f - t)}BB'e^{A'(t_f - t)}$$
I have used ' as transpose, and $e^{A(t_f - t)}$ is matrix exponential

I just found out some books (Rugh Chapter 9) have the following definition
$$W_c[t_0,t_f] = \int_{t_0}^{t_f}e^{A(t_0 - t)}BB'e^{A'(t_0 - t)}$$

I am unable to show that the two definition are exactly equal. With change of variable I end up with different limits. Any insights will be great.

Answer (score 1):

These are defined as reachability and controllability Gramians respectively. In control theory reachability is defined as the ability to drive the system from $0$ initial state to any final state in a finite time, i.e. $x(t_0)=0$ and $x(t_f)=x_f$. Controllability is defined as the ability to drive the system from any initial state to $0$ final state in a finite time, i.e. $x(t_0)=x_0$ and $x(t_f)=0$. This is why $t_f-t$ occurs in the first matrix and $t_0-t$ occurs in the second matrix.

These concepts are equivalent in linear continuous time systems. To see that

$$ W_r[t_0,t_f] = e^{A (t_f-t_0)} W_c[t_0, t_f] e^{A' (t_f-t_0)} $$

where $W_r[t_0,t_f]$ is the reachability Gramian (the first matrix in the question). Since the matrix $e^{A (t_f-t_0)}$ is always invertible, $\text{rank} W_r = \text{rank} W_c$.

However, reachability and controllability are not equivalent in linear discrete time systems, because of the finite modes.

Comment: Oh thanks... I totally forgot that about reachability even exists. I feel there is a certain level abuse of terminology in the controls texts. Thanks again